# Pandas - how to merge dataframes on datetime column of different format?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, timestamp

I have two dataframes that I need to merge based on date. The first dataframe looks like:

```
             Time Stamp  HP_1H_mean  Coolant1_1H_mean  Extreme_1H_mean
0   2019-07-26 07:00:00  410.637966        414.607081              0.0   
1   2019-07-26 08:00:00  403.521735        424.787366              0.0   
2   2019-07-26 09:00:00  403.143925        425.739639              0.0   
3   2019-07-26 10:00:00  410.542895        426.210538              0.0
...
17  2019-07-27 00:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   
18  2019-07-27 01:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   
19  2019-07-27 02:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   
20  2019-07-27 03:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0
```

The second is like this:

```
    Time Stamp  Qty Compl
0   2019-07-26  150
1   2019-07-27  20
2   2019-07-29  230
3   2019-07-30  230
4   2019-07-31  170
```

Both `Time Stamp` columns are `datetime64[ns]`. I wanted to merge left, and forward fill the date into all the other rows for a day. My problem is at the merge, the `Qty Compl` from the second df is applied at midnight of each day, and some days does not have a midnight time stamp, such as the first day in the first dataframe.

Is there a way to merge and match every row that contains the same day? The desired output would look like this:

```
         Time Stamp  HP_1H_mean  Coolant1_1H_mean  Extreme_1H_mean    Qty Compl
0   2019-07-26 07:00:00  410.637966        414.607081              0.0      150   
1   2019-07-26 08:00:00  403.521735        424.787366              0.0      150
2   2019-07-26 09:00:00  403.143925        425.739639              0.0      150
3   2019-07-26 10:00:00  410.542895        426.210538              0.0      150
...
17  2019-07-27 00:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0      20
18  2019-07-27 01:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0      20
19  2019-07-27 02:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0      20
20  2019-07-27 03:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0      20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with sorted both DataFrames by datetimes:

```
#if necessary
df1['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time Stamp'])
df2['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time Stamp'])
df1 = df1.sort_values('Time Stamp')
df2 = df2.sort_values('Time Stamp')

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Time Stamp')
print (df)
           Time Stamp  HP_1H_mean  Coolant1_1H_mean  Extreme_1H_mean  \
0 2019-07-26 07:00:00  410.637966        414.607081              0.0   
1 2019-07-26 08:00:00  403.521735        424.787366              0.0   
2 2019-07-26 09:00:00  403.143925        425.739639              0.0   
3 2019-07-26 10:00:00  410.542895        426.210538              0.0   
4 2019-07-27 00:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   
5 2019-07-27 01:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   
6 2019-07-27 02:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   
7 2019-07-27 03:00:00    0.000000          0.000000              0.0   

   Qty Compl  
0        150  
1        150  
2        150  
3        150  
4         20  
5         20  
6         20  
7         20
```

Comment: Awesome, I've never used `merge_asof`. It defaults to a left merge always it looks like? Thanks for the help, that's perfect. Will accept when the time's done... you were too quick ;)

Comment: @55thSwiss - yes, this is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date from the Time Stamp column, convert it to a string and then merge

```
df1['date']=df1['Time Stamp'].dt.date.astype(str)
df2['date']=df2['Time Stamp'].dt.date.astype(str)
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,how="left",on="date")
```