# Smart algo to merge 2 dataframes on datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, merge, timestamp

I have 2 dataframe, df1 is some traffic data:

```
id  mtm_id  date_p  travel_d    ut_p    travel_t
0   1   2020-11-25 14:50:04 22.206  2.426   53.864
1   1   2020-11-25 15:50:05 22.214  1.578   35.049
2   1   2020-11-25 16:50:05 22.214  1.766   39.227
3   1   2020-11-25 17:50:05 22.206  1.75    38.867
4   1   2020-11-25 18:50:04 22.206  1.533   34.044
... ... ... ... ... ...
7408    1   2021-10-02 19:50:06 22.205  1.502   33.358
7409    1   2021-10-02 20:50:14 22.205  1.37    30.42
7410    1   2021-10-02 21:50:05 22.205  1.342   29.791
7411    1   2021-10-02 22:50:09 22.205  1.296   28.777
7412    1   2021-10-02 23:50:06 22.688  1.196   27.144
```

and second df2 is weather data:

```
id date_w   temperature pressure    humidity    clouds  wind_speed
0   2017-04-09 16:00:00 281.4   1019    49  Clear : clear sky, 0%   4
1   2017-04-10 22:00:00 7.83    1012    81  Clear : ясно, 0%    3
2   2017-04-11 15:00:00 18  1002    42  Clear : ясно, 0%    9
3   2017-04-11 21:30:00 8.78    1003    93  Rain : дождь, 75%   5
4   2017-04-12 15:30:00 6.25    1002    60  Clouds : слегка облачно, 40%    5
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
7118    2021-10-03 06:17:52 4   1035    61  Clouds : облачно с прояснениями, 63%    2.08
7119    2021-10-03 12:18:14 10  1034    44  Clouds : облачно с прояснениями, 69%    2.1
7120    2021-10-03 18:17:42 5.19    1035    58  Rain : небольшой дождь, 100%    1.9
7121    2021-10-04 00:17:48 3.65    1036    71  Clouds : пасмурно, 98%  1.77
7122    2021-10-04 06:17:20 5.81    1037    71  Clouds : облачно с прояснениями, 55%    2.98
```

The data is collected independently, so the dates in the tables are different.
I need to append to each row in df1 the row from df2 closest in datetime ( min(abs(date_p-date_w)) to match (sync) traffic and proper weather data in time) in order to get final table:

```
id  mtm_id  date_p  travel_d    ut_p    travel_t date_w temperature pressure    humidity    clouds  wind_speed
```

I can do it in standard way with loops, but I'm wondering if there is any python-elegant way to do this in vector operations rather than step by step (I'm sure python gurus can do everything!))). It's also a question of speed of code execution, which also matters.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Try to use `merge_asof`.

Comment: I guess it works only if timestamps are equal, there is such solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375664/pandas-how-to-merge-dataframes-on-datetime-column-of-different-format 
But probably one can "blur" date_p somehow  in order to get it equal to date_w...

Comment: Is `id` column relevant for the merge?

Comment: No, forget it...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `merge_asof` works in this case perfectly, as Corralien said above ([Smart algo to merge 2 dataframes on datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152196/smart-algo-to-merge-2-dataframes-on-datetime-column?noredirect=1#comment124009240_70152196)) So, the solution [Pandas - how to merge dataframes on datetime column of different format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375664/pandas-how-to-merge-dataframes-on-datetime-column-of-different-format) works in this case too!